# creating a tridiagonal matrix in scilab/matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I want to create a tridiagonal matrix in scilab/matlab such that it uses for loops. 
I dont know how to create the matrix but here is what i have started

```
for i=2:n

   a_{1,1}=2 

   a_{i,i}=2

   a_{i,i-1}=1

   a_{i,i+1}=1

end
```

Thats the components of the matrix and if possible the other components which are zero will not be stored for efficient memory usage.

Comment: I'm unclear on the question. Is this homework where you have to use a `for` loop to do this? Or do you just need to create the matrix in any manner? Also, that is neither valid Matlab code nor how to mathematically represent a matrix. Please edit your question to show your actual code and/or TeX for a representative or arbitrary size [tridiagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix). Or just describe it in words.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB code:

```
n = 10; % order of the matrix
M = zeros(n,n);
for k=1:n
    M(k,k) = 2; % main diagonal
    if k<n
        M(k+1,k) = 1; % diagonal below main
        M(k,k+1) = 1; % diagonal above main
    end
end
```

I don't know how to define the matrix without storing the zeros, but I know it's called [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). These links might be helpful:

- [MATLAB Documentation - Sparse Matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html)
- [MATLAB Examples - Sparse Matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/sparse-matrices.html)